# What is a steam trade URL

Tags: bots, steam

I am new to steam API. I have been tasked to create a trade bot for a website which will use this to do steam trades, for example accept trade, offer, reject etc. Due to lack of good documentation of Steam, I am struggling to gather basic information actually.

So I want to understand these things:-

1. What is a trade URL?
2. How can the bot be able to do transaction on a user's behalf, i mean it's expected to make the transaction from bot's steam account for let's say accepting a trade offer made to a steam user with steamid 111 from another steam user with steamid 222? How it can be done?

Any information will be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I found realy nice documentation for Steam API. 
You can find it [here.](https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html)

Also, nice [resouce](https://github.com/SteamDatabase/SteamTracking) `SteamDatabase/SteamTracking`.

You can check Steam Service status using [this](https://steamstat.us/) service.

NodeJs [library](https://github.com/Tewki/CSGO-Item-Floats-From-Inspect-Links) `Tewki/CSGO-Item-Floats-From-Inspect-Links` to work with Steam API.

Hopefully, this information will be usefull.

Good luck.